# One git for multiple folders in differents places

Tags: git, repository, dotfiles

I think this subject was asked before, but I didn't find anything interesting to work with. I read this [Can I store the .git folder outside the files I want tracked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505467/can-i-store-the-git-folder-outside-the-files-i-want-tracked) and [Single Git repo with directories in multiple locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345917/single-git-repo-with-directories-in-multiple-locations) try to play with it, but didn't find the way to achieve this well.

The goal of this, is to store backup preferences for applications and dotfiles.

But the strucuture of files look to somethink like this

```
-- /Users/Jeremy/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User
------ Theme
------ Snippet
------ Preferences.sublime-settings
--
-- /Users/Jeremy/.gitconfig
--
-- /Users/Jeremy/.config/fish
------ config.fish
------ fish_history
```

Maybe the solution is to `init` the repository to "/Users/Jeremy" and make a big gitignore, but I think it's not the best way to do it.

So how can I create only one git repository on one place to manage all this different folders ?

Comment: That reminds me of http://blog.tfnico.com/2014/03/managing-dot-files-with-vcsh-and-myrepos.html and vcsh https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh (multiple Git repositories in $HOME). It was presented extensively at http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2013/06/gitminutes-13-richard-hartmann-on.html

Comment: I will take a look to this.

Comment: Maybe instead of blacklisting, whitelisting folders in your gitignore? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288712/gitignore-whitelist-on-directory-and-its-contents

Comment: Ok, I tried this solution as well, I make some test with the `.gitignore` add all my files from `~/.config` folder, something went wrong, and hop loose all my files. That's so bad :D

Comment: another similar idea to vcsh but a different implementation is multigit (https://github.com/capr/multigit) which is actually used as a git-based package manager

Answer (score 2):

> how can I create only one git repository on one place to manage all this different folders ?

That is what the [project vcsh](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh) is for: one git repo for your different configs, but:

> vcsh allows you to maintain several Git repositories in one single directory. They all maintain their working trees without clobbering each other or interfering otherwise.

See an example in "[Managing dot-files with vcsh and myrepos](http://blog.tfnico.com/2014/03/managing-dot-files-with-vcsh-and-myrepos.html)", and vcsh presentation in "[GitMinutes #13: Richard Hartmann on Managing Your Homedir with vcsh](http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2013/06/gitminutes-13-richard-hartmann-on.html)"

Comment: This isn't the opposite of what I want to do ? Several Git repositories in one single directory whereas I want to track several directories with the same Git repository ?

Comment: @jbr I agree, but from the presentation his author gave in GitMinutes,that seemed actually a better solution.