# Limit recursivity of a git repository

Tags: git, dotfiles

I have created a git repository on my home directory (/home/user/.git) to "backup" and save alle changes from my dotfiles.

To solve this I have implmeneted a gitignore where I explicit ignore all files excepting the wanted dotfiles.

But know I can access the git repository from everywhere (home/user/folder1, home/userfolder2) - Can I limit the recursivity from a git repository, so only the directory /home/user is under vcs?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16183043/3001761

Comment: This does not solve my problem. Basically I can enter "git status" in /home/user/folder1 and it shows me the information about the git repository...

Comment: Yes; you're ignoring it, but still within the repo. Have you considered symlinking in your dotfiles from elsewhere?

Comment: hmmm, yeah! This should be a solution - not perfect, but it will work! thanks so far. Perhaps someone else have a other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symlinking the dotfile is one solution.
I mentioned before in "[One git for multiple folders in differents places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24256711/6309)" the [**project vcsh**](https://github.com/RichiH/vcsh): one git repo for your different configs, but:

> vcsh allows you to maintain several Git repositories in one single directory. They all maintain their working trees without clobbering each other or interfering otherwise.

See an example in "[Managing dot-files with vcsh and myrepos](http://blog.tfnico.com/2014/03/managing-dot-files-with-vcsh-and-myrepos.html)", and vcsh presentation in "[GitMinutes #13: Richard Hartmann on Managing Your Homedir with vcsh](http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2013/06/gitminutes-13-richard-hartmann-on.html)"

That is another approach to trying to have a repo directly in one's $HOME (having to exclude any subfolder).

Comment: I haven't used vcsh, but I agree with the fundamental mechanism - make your `GIT_DIR` something like `.dotfiles.git` so that you have to be explicit about managing them and you don't accidentally mix up repos.  vcsh seems like a reasonable approach to make this easier.

Comment: I have choosen the solution with a separate folder for my dotfiles and link it via ln to my $HOME directory. Thanks!

Comment: Another way to manage your dotfiles with symlinks is with GNU stow. check  it out. There are lots of examples on Github, i use it to manage my dotfiles and it's great [my dotfiles](https://github.com/aurelien-rainone/dotfiles)